# Weblogic to tomcat migration performance issue

Tags: java, performance, tomcat

We successfully migrated our web applications from Weblogic to tomcat 7.
The web application is built using.

1. Spring
2. Jsp
3. Uses the weblogic Datasources

When we migrated to Tomcat we started using DBCP. But thinking to change to Tomcat JDBC Connection pooling. Please suggest would this be helpful.

The application has to perform some heavy transactions on the server side.

But the tomcat fails to deliver the performance and stability which we get in weblogic.

There are too many GC thread running on tomcat and this makes the application to hang. Almost 2/7 of the total time is spent on GC.

Here is the JVM initialization string

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -server -Xms120G -Xmx120G -Xmn60G -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:MaxNewSize=40G -XX:NewSize=40G -Xloggc:$CATALINA_HOME/logs/gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+UseLargePages -XX:LargePageSizeInBytes=1200m"
```

Please help me to tune the tomcat for better performance and stability.

Comment: Did you also use generational JVM and a heap size of 120G in Weblogic? So much size must be harmful in the way you point (GC time).

Comment: In weblogic we did not specify the generation size. In tomcat due to bad performance we were trying different combinations of JVM options. So we specified the settings.

Comment: 120G for heap size sounds like a hell of a lot. How much RAM do you have available? Are you sure you need so much memory? Have you tried with something more handleable (less than 10G)?

Comment: We have a physical memory of 140GB. We have lot of data which is stored as Cache. Around 70GB of data is stored as Cache and we need the remaining memory of 50GB for the processing threads.

Comment: @Shivanand What size does the actual process reach (not just the heap)?

Comment: It reaches the size of around 110 - 112 GB during peak hours. Then it comes down to 70 - 75 GB if there is not Load on the system.

Comment: @Shivanand Just checking that figure is the total virtual memory usage of the process, not just the physical memory in use by the OS. What I'm wondering was whether you're process ever gets pushed into swap. That would significantly affect the GC overhead.

Comment: Consider using JDK 7 Update 4+, Oracle introduced G1 garbage collector in this version, which prevents ALL UNIVERSE STOPS FOR GC. That would help alot.

Answer (score 3):

A few questions immediately jump out:

- What profiling and analysis have you done to lead you to believe that
  you need 120 GiB of heap space?
- Are you aware of the GC implications
  of a very large heap?
- Do you have enough physical memory for the
  entire Java process, not just the heap?
- Why are you explicitly
  setting the max size of the young generation to 60 GiB and new to 40 GiB?

If we take a look at the options you've specified:

```
-server 
-Xms120G 
-Xmx120G 
-Xmn60G 
-XX:PermSize=512m 
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m 
-XX:MaxNewSize=40G 
-XX:NewSize=40G 
-XX:+PrintGCDetails 
-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps 
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC 
-XX:+CMSIncrementalMode 
-XX:+DisableExplicitGC 
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled 
-XX:+UseLargePages 
-XX:LargePageSizeInBytes=1200m
```

**It reads like a list by someone who's read one too many 'Java performance' blogs.** If you can't explain what each option does and why you've added it as an argument, remove the option.

Typically, the JVM handles itself well - often making better decisions about things like how much eden space it needs etc. If you're going to set much more than the heap and perm gen sizes (and even then...) you really need to know what you're doing...

Unfortunately, **there are no magic settings** and that's especially true if your application is particularly heavy.

Start from a set of realistic base settings, use tools like JVisualVM, JMeter, MAT et al. to look at an overview of the behaviour of your application. Record metrics on performance, heap usage, concurrent threads, throughput (peak and average), time spent doing garbage collection and the stability of your app. Each time you make a change, record the same metrics and record the results. Eventually, you'll have an application tuned properly and you'll understand whether each setting is actually having a positive effect on performance.

Comment: +1, it's possible the OP has done vigorous testing and research to come to those settings, but if so, to diagnose the problem, some of those details need to be in the question

Comment: We done all this analysis and deployed our code on weblogic. But later the business team decided to use Tomcat. So we ported our code to use tomcat. So i just wanted to know if there is there any differences between tomcat and weblogic as such?? I seriously feel that everything depends on the underlying JVM and not on the application server or Servlet container. But was surprised to see such kind differences between both the servers.

Comment: @Shivanand As Disco states, we need to know what you've done. What your base settings were, what you changed, why you changed them and what (if any) affect each change had. Otherwise, it's not possible to go beyond generalised advice.

Comment: The only thing which we changed in the base settings was explicitly defining Young generation size, Old generation size. but that does not seem to help me. So i was just thinking to remove those settings. We also added parameter to use LargeFiles. That certainly helped to reduce the initial cache size and built up time.So we are thinking to stick with it. One more thing is the connection pool handling is different in Weblogic and Tomcat.Apart from this there is nothing which we changed between Weblogic and Tomcat.

Comment: @Shivanand It'd be really useful if you provide further details in your question. A very high level of the type of application, traffic pattern and the analysis you did to come up with your JVM options. When you transferred to Tomcat - did you move physical servers - is their any architectural difference (OS, JVM etc.) that may have an effect?